# finding unique headers in a fasta file using linux command line

Tags: fasta, linux

I tried to use the following command

```
uniq -u reference.fasta >> reference_uniq.fasta
```

I'd like a count of the unique headers.

Comment: does it matter what the output order of the unique headers is?

Answer (score 5):

If you just want the number of unique headers, you can do this:

```
grep '>' reference.fasta | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

If you want a list of the unique headers, you can do this:

```
grep '>' reference.fasta | sort | uniq
```

If you want a histogram of how many times each header occurs, you can do this:

```
grep '>' reference.fasta | sort | uniq -c | awk '{printf("%s\t%s\n", $1, $2)}'
```

Answer (score 3):

The `uniq` command expects sorted input. Interestingly, the `sort` command actually has a "unique" option, `-u`, which means `uniq` is not strictly needed. For the fastest processing, you can look for the '>' character at the start of lines with grep:

```
grep '^>' reference.fasta | sort -u > reference_headers_unique.fasta
```

For returning the *number* of unique lines, pipe through `wc -l`:

```
grep '^>' reference.fasta | sort -u | wc -l
```

For more information about regular expressions, see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/grep-regular-expression-syntax.html#grep-regular-expression-syntax).

Comment: This seems like the best solution given, just note it assumes that the desired output order for the unique headers is the order provided by `sort` (which may not be stable depending on the locale)

Answer (score 1):

If, for some reason, you need to keep the original order of the input file, so you only want the *first* occurrence of each header, you can do:

```
awk '/^>/ && !a[$0]++' reference.fasta > headers
```

Or, to get the number only:

```
awk '/^>/ && !a[$0]++{k++}; END{print k}' reference.fasta
```

However, these only make sense if you need to keep the order of the original file. If not, use [Gringer's `grep` approach](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/5188/298) which will be much faster (`reference.fasta` is hg19):

```
$ time awk '/^>/ && !a[$0]++{k++}; END{print k}' reference.fasta 
93

real    0m34.510s
user    0m31.861s
sys     0m2.634s

$ time grep '^>' reference.fasta | sort -u | wc -l
93

real    0m16.597s
user    0m0.820s
sys     0m3.725s
```

Comment: +1 for order capturing approach and benchmark, I guess ripgrep might be even faster